# Render a PDF from a Byte Stream for a JSF Screen(Prime Faces)

Tags: jsf, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a requirement where a PDF steam deliver as a byte array needs to be rendered for a user in a JSF screen - the PDF is being generated by an external source which returns a byte array - converting the byte stream to a PDF and writing to disk works fine but I need to generate a dialog asking the user to open the PDF or save it to a location on their disk - I have been able to do this using Struts with the request object - is there an example of how to accomplish the same with JSF ?

Thanks